# Css: min contains 2 expressions with different units

Tags: css, frontend, css-calc

`height: min(483px, 100vw * 0.82)`

Error: px and vw are not comoatible units

How to get the min between the 2 values above ? Or transform the vw to px ?

Comment: your code is fine, you only have an extra `)`

Comment: You have a spurious closing bracket in the CSS you have given. Without it the setting works fine, at least on Edge on Windows10. Where did the error message come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping with `calc` solved the problem:

`height: calc(min(483px, 100vw * 0.82));`